# usb Ethernet adapter disapear after Stoping network-manager service

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, ethernet, ifconfig

I am using D-Link (DUB-E100) for handling 2 seperated network under linux ubuntu 14.04. at first i have 2 eth on my system .

**ifconfig yields**:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:70:27:3e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.200  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baae:edff:fe70:273e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13717 errors:0 dropped:35 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1262738 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:82012 (82.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:b8:0a:ef:cf:c6  
          inet addr:192.168.0.183  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56b8:aff:feef:cfc6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:117675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17937811 (17.9 MB)  TX bytes:3777428 (3.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:344851 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:344851 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:26624855 (26.6 MB)  TX bytes:26624855 (26.6 MB)
```

but after this command :
**sudo service network-manager stop**
Here is what I get in **ifconfig**:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:70:27:3e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.200  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baae:edff:fe70:273e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13717 errors:0 dropped:35 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1262738 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:96519 (96.5 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:346012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:346012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:26759532 (26.7 MB)  TX bytes:26759532 (26.7 MB)
```

,So in this situation i lost my second network ,(i have to stop network-manager beacaus before stopping it,I dont recieve any udp packet from other local devices on my local area network (eth0)), how can I have two connection simultaneously,
is there any way to have eth1 after stopping network-manager?

**UPDATE1:**
My /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I changed My /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

and it could not solve my problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `eth1` interface is managed by Network Manager.

When you stop the service, the interface is disabled.

You can setup `/etc/network/interfaces` and not use NM for both devices.

But your problem is mainly because you did not set proper routing and iptables.

Comment: I have updated my question according to your replay ,But changing interfaces could not solve my problem